# XNA soundEffectInstance set to loop, does not loop

Tags: xna, c#, sound-effects

Using the code below I can play background music, this works. Eventhough I've set 'IsLooped' to 'true', the sound won't loop.

What Am I doing wrong?

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // background music
        SoundEffect bgEffect;
        bgEffect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("background_music");
        SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance = bgEffect.CreateInstance();
        soundEffectInstance.IsLooped = true;
        soundEffectInstance.Play();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've stored your `SoundEffectInstance` as a local variable. Which means that it will go out of scope when your `LoadContent` method exits.

When the garbage collector runs, later, it will notice that nothing is referencing your `SoundEffectInstance` - so it cleans it up. This, of course, stops the sound from playing.

The fix is simple. Simply move the variable declaration outside of your `LoadContent` method, making it a member of your game class:

```
SoundEffect bgEffect;
SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    bgEffect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("background_music");
    soundEffectInstance = bgEffect.CreateInstance();
    soundEffectInstance.IsLooped = true;
    soundEffectInstance.Play();
}
```

This will keep the reference around for as long as your game class is around.

(Note that I've moved `bgEffect` out as well, in the above code. But technically you don't have to, because `Content` keeps a reference internally to everything it loads, until you call `Content.Unload()`.)